# Running two Async Functions where one returns data and another returns Nothing using Asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Lets say I have some tasks I want to run asynchronously.

I want to make a series of 4 API calls asynchronously, but I also would like to have another asynchronous function checking on status of my session.

Using `asyncio` I have tried:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
async def make_request():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://httpbin.org/get') as resp:
            print(resp.status)
            print(await resp.text())

    return resp

async def say_hello():
    print("Hello")

async def main():

    tasks = []
    for i in range(4):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(make_request()))

    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, say_hello(),)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

In reality, my `say_hello()` is checking a status and updating a class attribute (the session) while making requests according to a set time frequency. How could I accomplish this "status" function running alongside my actual API calls execution in `make_request()` which return a response object which I later process when finished.

Comment: From what I see, you should add `()` to `make_request`, i.e. `tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(make_request()))`

Comment: @bzu Ok, yes that was a typo, but not my issue. I want the results to not include the ```None``` Result that is returned from the ```say_hello()```, or would I simply need an extra process to filter out the ```None``` from teh resulting ```results```

Comment: If you don't want None in your result list, just throw it out.  Add a line `results = [a for a in results if a is not None]` before the end of main.  However, Andrej Kessaly's answer is a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should structure your code a little bit differently. Lets make `while True:` loop in `say_hello()` and put `await asyncio.sleep(N)` there. Move `say_hello()` out of `asyncio.gather`:

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def make_request():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("http://httpbin.org/get") as resp:
            resp.status
            await resp.text()
            await asyncio.sleep(2)  # sleep here artificially

    return resp


async def say_hello():
    while True:
        # update session here
        # ...
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("Hello")


async def main():

    tasks = []
    for i in range(4):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(make_request()))

    asyncio.create_task(say_hello())

    results = await asyncio.gather(
        *tasks,
    )

    print(results)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

---

EDIT: Example with global session:

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

session = None
headers = {"MySessionHeader": "0"}

# limit concurrency of connections to 2
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)


async def make_request():
    async with sem, session.get(
        "http://httpbin.org/get", headers=headers
    ) as resp:
        resp.status
        print(await resp.text())
        await asyncio.sleep(2)  # sleep here artificially
    return resp


async def update_headers():
    count = 1
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        # update headers of session:
        # eg. update cookies/headers
        headers["MySessionHeader"] = str(count)
        count += 1


async def main():
    global session
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    tasks = []
    for i in range(24):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(make_request()))

    asyncio.create_task(update_headers())

    results = await asyncio.gather(
        *tasks,
    )

    print(results)

    await session.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: so ```asyncio.create_task(say_hello())``` will start running asynchronously first, and then gather will pick up the tasks for requests? I'm pretty new to ```asyncio``` and didn't realize you could do that. I thought you had to put your tasks together in ```gather```. This is great! One further thought. If I am doing this all in a class and am updating an attribute like ```self.session```, is there any concern for race conditions here? E.g. if my ```make_requests()``` is using ```self.session``` and ```say_hello()``` is refreshing that ```self.session```

Comment: @Coldchain9 I've updated my answer with global session. For your question about race conditions - it depends. According this answer on github it's probably bad idea (https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3299#issuecomment-425218264). But if you structure your code around it's what you want. Me personally I would send headers/cookies explicitly with each request.

Comment: So you think that updating something like ```self.headers``` in parallel and sending the headers in to each request would alleviate race condition problems? This seems like a great idea because then I don't have to worry about closing prior session and setting new one, whereas with each request it will use my ```self.headers```. I think this makes sense. Now to test!

Comment: This seems to be working but only if I include ```await asyncio.sleep(1)``` in my ```update_headers()``` within the ```while loop```. If I do not, the while loop seems to be taking control of everything and my api requests do not fire. Is there a reason for needing the sleep (to pass back control to the event loop) or something?